# Checkbox doesn't work, but the label does

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, label

I have a label and a checkbox. When I click the label the desired action occurs. The checkbox does nothing, neither when I click to enable or disable. I have moved the label both inside and outside of the input and nothing seems to work. All code is below.

home_filters.html.erb:

```
<span id="listing-search-sentence-transit" style="display: none;">I'd like to live near <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-transit-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">these trains.</a></span>
<span id="listing-search-sentence-fee" style="display: none;">Only find me <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-no-fee-selector" role="button" <%= f.check_box :no_fee %> <%= f.label :no_fee, "no fee listings." %> </a></span>
<span id="listing-search-sentence-pets" style="display: none;"> <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-pets-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover"><%= f.label :pets %></a></span>


<div id="test-content" class="hide">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <label id="label-sentence-fee" class="general-text-label" for="sentence-fee"><input type="checkbox" name="label-sentence-fee" id="sentence-fee"> No Fee Listing</label><br>
    <label id="label-sentence-transit" class="general-text-label" for="sentence-transit"><input type="checkbox" name="label-sentence-transit" id="sentence-transit"> Transit</label><br>
    <label id="label-sentence-pets" class="general-text-label" for="sentence-pets"><input type="checkbox" name="label-sentence-pets" id="sentence-pets"> Pets</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

.js file:

```
$("#sentence-fee").click(function(feeEvent){
  feeEvent.stopPropagation();
  $("#listing-search-sentence-fee").toggle();
  $("input#sentence-fee").prop('checked', true);
});

$("#sentence-transit").click(function(transitEvent){
  transitEvent.stopPropagation();
  $("#listing-search-sentence-transit").toggle();
  $("input#sentence-transit").prop('checked', true);
});

$("#sentence-pets").click(function(petsEvent){
  petsEvent.stopPropagation();
  $("#listing-search-sentence-pets").toggle();
  $("input#sentence-pets").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: `$("input#sentence-fee").prop('checked', true);` why you do this? do you want to have always checked input on click?

Comment: @demo I do not. Only when a user checks the box.

Comment: If you remove this line `$("input#sentence-fee").prop('checked', true);` is it want you expext? When user click on checkBox - it become checked. Second time - it is unchecked. Some thing like this https://jsfiddle.net/xk9toseq/

Comment: @demo Correct. As of right now the checkbox is just there and does nothing. So, if I person clicks the checkbox the desired action should appear. On the second click, the desired action will disappear. I removed that line and it did nothing.

Comment: Desired Action - do you mean toggle of `#listing-search-sentence-pets` element?

Comment: @demo That is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147109/discussion-between-demo-and-mike-wiesenhart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have code like the following example, should work for you:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="listing-search-sentence-transit" style="display: none;">I'd like to live near <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-transit-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover">these trains.</a></span>
<span id="listing-search-sentence-fee" style="display: none;">Only find me <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-no-fee-selector" role="button" <%= f.check_box :no_fee %> <%= f.label :no_fee, "no fee listings." %> </a></span>
<span id="listing-search-sentence-pets" style="display: none;"> <a tabindex="0" class="button btn-transparent" id="listing-pets-selector" role="button" data-toggle="popover"><%= f.label :pets %></a></span>


<div id="test-content" class="hide">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <label id="label-sentence-fee" class="general-text-label" for="sentence-fee"><input type="checkbox" name="label-sentence-fee" id="sentence-fee"> No Fee Listing</label><br>
    <label id="label-sentence-transit" class="general-text-label" for="sentence-transit"><input type="checkbox" name="label-sentence-transit" id="sentence-transit"> Transit</label><br>
    <label id="label-sentence-pets" class="general-text-label" for="sentence-pets"><input type="checkbox" name="label-sentence-pets" id="sentence-pets"> Pets</label><br>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sentence-fee").click(function(feeEvent) {
      $("#listing-search-sentence-fee").toggle();
    });

    $("#sentence-transit").click(function(transitEvent) {
      $("#listing-search-sentence-transit").toggle();
    });

    $("#sentence-pets").click(function(petsEvent) {
      $("#listing-search-sentence-pets").toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I updated my code and the checkboxes still are not working.

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart do you have any CSS that might cover the checkbox, or your checkbox have negative z-index

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart to debug, remove all your code from the page also css, and only use the above code, does that work? if it is working, move the stuff back one by one you can find out which element or code breaking it.

Answer (score -1):

It's always get the parent element event, if he has it.

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: This answer makes no sense in its current state. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: If I have a `label` involving an `input`, I will never be able to get` click` events on the `input`, only on the` label`. In `input`, you can use` onChange`.

Comment: Do u understand ?